# JsSIP: User is logged out when browser refreshed

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sip, jssip

I have a simple browser SIP phone. It is a single page application which is based on the JsSIP library.
It has two input fields login and password. After authentication it shows me a dial panel. When I refresh a page it shows me again authentication form.

How to restore a session after a page refresh and keep user logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You can't save the login session of JsSIP in browser cache like HTTP auth.

JsSIP does a SIP session over Websocket to server.

You have to pass user credentials to JsSIP `new JsSIP.UA(configuration);` each time a browser reloads/refresh. Maybe you can store the credentials in browser cookie or localStorage and use it to initialise JsSIP on refresh. But security is up to you decide on which environment your app runs.